# How to get Current Quality Label from JWPlayer with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I'm trying to get Current Quality Label from JWPlayer 7 with JS, but it's returning the Quality numbers, e.g: 1, 2, 3... Instead of defined Label: 360p, 480p, 720p...

I'm using this:

```
playerInstance.getCurrentQuality();
//it returns: 1 or 2 or 3 stream number
```

I also tried this:

```
playerInstance.getQualityLevels();
//it returns: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

also tried with:

```
playerInstance.getQualityLevels('label');
//not luck, it returns the same from above: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Is there any other workaround to get the **Current Quality Label**?

Answer (score 0):

You could get an array of strings (instead of an array of objects) using Array.prototype.map:

```
var levels = playerInstance.getQualityLevels().map(function (o) { return o.label; })
```

Then, I think you can use the number from getCurrentQuality as an index:

```
var level = levels[playerInstance.getCurrentQuality()];
```